# Is there a secure way to connect to an IMAP server on behalf of a user?

Tags: security, passwords, gmail

I'm working on a web application which involves connecting to Gmail on behalf of a user to check for new messages. Is there a way to securely store the user's credentials so that they can still be recovered for the login, or is there some way to obtain a token for Gmail to use in connections?

EDIT: The application is meant to be used mostly with mobile users, so they won't be logging into the site frequently.  Thus, storing information in a cookie isn't viable.

Answer (score 2):

If you logged into GMail's web interface it gives you a token in the form of a cookie.  If yYou could use that token and the web interface then you could access their email without storing their credentials.  Of course that isn't IMAP access, and it expires (as a good token should).

Alternatively you could encrypt their credentials with a value you store as a cookie on their computer.  Then when they access your site you can check their mail without ever storing the encrypted credentials with the key to decrypt it.

Neither is an ideal solution, but hopefully they get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: I thought of some sort of cookie-based solution, but the application will mostly support mobile users, so storing information in a cookie isn't ideal.